# Why Windows Live Photo Gallery stopped displaying thumbnails, and how to fix it?

Tags: windows-7, images, media, windows-live-photo

I now get this instead, for most (but not all) photos. This is the icon which represents the WLPG application, I think.

[image]

Some observations:

- I can see the thumbnails fine in Explorer, which is where a lot of other people have this problem.
- My C:\ drive may have temporarily filled up at some point recently, but then was cleaned up.
- Double-clicking on the photo will display it fine, so I know it's not file corruption or permissions issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was to delete the ".pd5" file from c:\users... (it was a few days ago and I forgot the exact file location).

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Windows Live Photo Gallery.
2. Click Start, click Run, type `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Photo Gallery`, and then click OK.
3. Delete any existing instance of `OLD_Pictures.pd4` and `OLD_Pictures.pd5`.
4. Locate and then right-click `Pictures.pd4` or `Pictures.pd5`.
5. Rename `Pictures.pd4` to `OLD_Pictures.pd4` or rename `Pictures.pd5` to `OLD_Pictures.pd5`.

Note: Windows Live Photo Gallery must be closed to perform this repair. When you restart Windows Live Photo Gallery, the database will be rebuilt.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/944221